# Cant return html string in to browser

Tags: php, return, concatenation

I have built an html string that is used for 2 purposes:

1. output to browser
2. Send as a fully formatted email.

This script work perfect for sending email but not for outputting the the browser. Here is the basic build:

```
  function makeformatedmessage(){ 
  $message = '';
  $message .= '
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Some title</title>
  </head>
  <body>';

  $message .='complex html body';
  $message .='complex html body 2';
  $message .='</body>
  </html>';

  return $message;

 }
```

When I send this as an email everything is sent but when i output to the browser only   $message .='complex html body 2' part of the message is missing. Is there a better way to store html and output to the browser.

**EDITED**
I descovered through closer debugging that there was a another file with the same function that was been called in the browser. After I removed it it worked as it should.

Comment: How are you displaying it in the browser?

Comment: You might have to post that "complex html body". I can't test right now but I'm almost certain this specific example (`echo makeformatedmessage();`) would work just fine.

Comment: I output the browser like this: echo makeformatedmessage();

Answer (score 2):

When I run:

```
 <?php

 function makeformatedmessage(){ 
 $message = '';
 $message .= '
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Some title</title>
 </head>
 <body>';

 $message .='complex html body';
 $message .='complex html body 2';
 $message .='</body>
    </html>';

 return $message;

}

echo makeformatedmessage();

?>
```

The source output to my browser (as expected) is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>complex html bodycomplex html body 2</body>
</html>
```